# ant design image crop not cropping

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I use antd image crop i follow the code but the result only upload the full picture not the cropped picture. How to make the crop function work?
Did i miss something? please tell me if you know what i miss so i can make the crop function work

```
const Homepage = () => {
const [fileList, setFileList] = useState<UploadFile<any>[]>([
    {
      uid: '-1',
      name: 'image.png',
      status: 'done',
      url: 'https://zos.alipayobjects.com/rmsportal/jkjgkEfvpUPVyRjUImniVslZfWPnJuuZ.png',
    },
  ]);
 
  const onChange: UploadProps['onChange'] = ({ fileList: newFileList }) => {
    setFileList(newFileList);
  };
  const onPreview = async (file: UploadFile) => {
    let src = file.url as string;
    if (!src) {
      src = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file.originFileObj as RcFile);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result as string);
      });
    }
    const image = new (Image as any)();
    image.src = src;
    const imgWindow = window.open(src);
    imgWindow?.document.write(image.outerHTML);
  };

  return (
    <Box>
<div className="centering">
<ImgCrop  >
      <Upload
        action="https://run.mocky.io/v3/435e224c-44fb-4773-9faf-380c5e6a2188"
        listType="picture-card"
        fileList={fileList}
        onChange={onChange}
        onPreview={onPreview}
        beforeUpload={()=> false}
        showUploadList={{
          showPreviewIcon:false
        }}
       
      >
        {fileList.length < 1 && '+ Upload'}
      </Upload>
      
    </ImgCrop>

    </div>
 );
};

export default Homepage;
```